# Launch comand, doctrine:query:sql with command ( Symfony 6 )

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, symfony6

I want to create one file Command for add SQL file with data on my BDD with Symfony command.

When i use:

`php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "$(< ./sql/zones.sql)"`, this command work.

But when i try on my file command :

```
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{

   $command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:query:sql');

   $files = ['$(< ./sql/zones.sql)'];

   foreach ($files as $file){

       $arguments = [
           'sql' => $file
       ];

       $greetInput = new ArrayInput($arguments);

       $command->run($greetInput, $output);
   }



}
```

they return me SQLSTATE[42000] so i think he don't found the file.

I try to change the path of $file

```
'../../sql/zones.sql',
'./sql/zones.sql',
'"$(< ./sql/zones.sql)"',
'"$(< ../../sql/zones.sql)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this with :

```
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) :int
    {

        $command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:query:sql');
        $files = ['./sql/zones.sql', './sql/status.sql', './sql/zone_prioritaire.sql', './sql/villes.sql', './sql/rememberMe.sql'];

        foreach ($files as $file){

            if (file_exists($file)){
                $arguments = [
                    'command' => 'doctrine:query:sql',
                    'sql' => trim(file_get_contents($file))
                ];

                $greetInput = new ArrayInput($arguments);

                $command->run($greetInput, $output);
            } else {

                throw new Exception("File '{$file}'not found.");
            }

        }


        return Command::SUCCESS;

    }
```